# Data frame column names after split

Tags: r, dataframe

When executing the following code

```
data <- data.frame( A = c("foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"),
                    B = c("foo","bar", "foo", "bar"),
                    C = c("bla", "foo", "bla", "bar"),
                    D = c(1, 2, 3, 4 ),
                    E = c(5, 6, 7, 8 ))

ds <- split(data, list(data$A, data$B, data$C), drop=TRUE)
write.table(ds[1], file="foo.csv", append=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

foo.csv looks like this:

```
 "bar.bar.bar.A","bar.bar.bar.B","bar.bar.bar.C","bar.bar.bar.D","bar.bar.bar.E"
 "bar","bar","bar",4,8
```

i.e., the column names contain the contents of the columns used to split. How do I change does names back to the original ones in a generic way? (I don't want to assign column names like "A", "B",....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `split` is a `list`. `ds[1]` returns a `list`, while `ds[[1]]` returns the value within that first list item.

Example:

```
ds[1]
# $bar.bar.bar
#     A   B   C D E
# 4 bar bar bar 4 8

ds[[1]]
#     A   B   C D E
# 4 bar bar bar 4 8
```

To get the output properly written as a CSV file, you need to extract the actual `data.frame`, so you need to use the `ds[[1]]` approach.

```
write.table(ds[[1]], file="foo.csv", append=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

If you wanted to write all of the `data.frame`s to separate CSV files, you can do something like:

```
lapply(names(ds), function(x) {
  write.table(ds[[x]], file = paste(x, ".csv", collapse = ""),
              append = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
})
```

This will create four CSV files (named bar.bar.bar.csv, bar.foo.bla.csv, foo.foo.bla.csv, and foo.bar.foo.csv) in your working directory.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Writing to separate files is exactly what I want to do!